# Quantum Haar Wavelet Transform

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state

I am working on understanding the quantum haar wavelet transform and trying to understand how it actually do the dimension reduction mathematically. A lot of people suggested me to read this paper : https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9809004.pdf, but this paper is too difficult to understand. I need some kind of detailed answer or a video link.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you be more specific as to what exactly you find unclear about it? Otherwise it might be hard for people to give an answer that would actually be useful to you, without knowing your current level of understanding

Comment: Thank you @gIS for your response. I really donot understand how SWAP gates at input and output form permutation matrices and only a Hadamard gates between input and ouput permutation matrices is able to do dimension reduction. The book I am presently reading i.e, "Dancing With Qubits" has not covered anything on Wavelet Transform.